# Display the name of syntax table for the current buffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I find out, what syntax table is used in the current buffer?

<kbd>C-h s</kbd> displays syntax table itself, but it's name isn't mentioned there...or at least I can't find it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are confusing a Lisp variable and its syntax-table value.  A syntax table does not have a name.

It sounds like you want the name of a variable whose current value is the current syntax table.  If so, this is generally misguided.

A syntax table need not be associated with a variable at all.

What you can do, however, is to see whether the current major mode has a variable named `MODENAME-mode-syntax-table`, where `MODENAME` is the major-mode name. This is a convention that is commonly followed whenever a major mode has its own syntax table.  See the Elisp manual, node `Major Mode Conventions`.

If that is the case, then just check the value of `MODENAME-mode-syntax-table`. If there is no such variable then at least you'll find that out.  And you can also check whether the current syntax table is equal to the value of that variable.  If there is no such variable, you can at least check whether the current syntax table is equal to the value of variable `standard-syntax-table`.

That's about all you can do, to get something similar to the "name of the current syntax table".

But this sounds like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). IOW, perhaps you should say why you are looking for the table "name". State the real problem you are trying to solve (as a separate question).

---

Update: command to show the syntax table of a given syntax variable in human-readable form.

```lisp
(defun describe-syntax-variable (variable)
  "Describe the syntax specifications for the given syntax VARIABLE.
The descriptions are inserted in a help buffer, which is then displayed."
  (interactive
   (let ((v                             (variable-at-point))
     (enable-recursive-minibuffers  t)
     val)
     (setq val (completing-read (if (symbolp v)
                    (format
                     "Describe syntax variable (default %s): " v)
                  "Describe syntax variable: ")
                obarray
                (lambda (vv)
                                  (or (get vv 'variable-documentation)
                                      (and (boundp vv)  (not (keywordp vv)))))
                t nil nil
                (and (symbolp v) (symbol-name v))))
     (list (if (equal val "") v (intern val)))))
  (help-setup-xref (list #'describe-syntax-variable variable)
           (called-interactively-p 'interactive))
  (with-help-window (help-buffer)
    (with-current-buffer standard-output
      (setq variable  (symbol-value variable))
      (describe-vector variable 'internal-describe-syntax-value)
      (while (setq variable  (char-table-parent variable))
        (insert "\nThe parent syntax table is:")
        (describe-vector variable 'internal-describe-syntax-value)))))
```

Comment: It looks like syntax table is indeed a value of an ELisp variable. I was able to confirmed it using <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `MODENAME-mode-syntax-table`.

Although it doesn't display the table properly (like <kbd>C-h s</kbd>), but it's enough for me, because I only wanted to confirm, whether there is a special table for a major mode.

Thank you :)

Comment: I added some code that shows the variable value as does `C-h s`.

Comment: Wow, this is just what I needed. Even though I've migrated from Vim to Emacs only recenlty and this being my first experience with functional programming, it was enough to put this block of code into my `init.el` and I was able to invoke command `describe-syntax-variable` using `M-x describe-syntax-variable`. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: FYI - all I did was take the code for `describe-syntax` and adjust it slightly to (a) prompt for a variable (code taken from `describe-variable`) and (b) use the value of that variable, instead of the syntax table of the current buffer. The point is that it is typically pretty easy to come up with your own, customized commands in Emacs.